# Coldfusion form values to php setcookie()

Tags: php, cookies, coldfusion

I have a Coldfusion page with posted form values that I'm passing to a php page (via cfhttp).  Example of the Coldfusion code:

```
<cfhttp method="Post" url="https://www.test.com/ssl/get_cookies.php" result="cookieResponse">
        <cfoutput>
            <cfif isdefined( "ppcid" )><cfhttpparam name="PPCID" type="formField" value="#session.ppcid#"></cfif>
            <cfif isdefined( "cid" )><cfhttpparam name="CID" type="formField" value="#session.cid#"></cfif>
            <cfif isdefined( "leadcomm" )><cfhttpparam name="LEADCOMM" type="formField" value="#LEADCOMM#"></cfif>
            <cfif isdefined( "clk" )><cfhttpparam name="CLK" type="formField" value="#CLK#"></cfif>
            <cfif isdefined( "dck" )><cfhttpparam name="DCK" type="formField" value="#DCK#"></cfif>
            <cfif isdefined( "ccid" )><cfhttpparam name="CCID" type="formField" value="#CCID#"></cfif>

        </cfoutput>
</cfhttp>
```

After I post these values to get_cookie.php, I want to set these values as cookies.  Here is an example of my get_cookies.php code:

```
    setcookie("LEADCOM", getVariable('LEADCOMM'), time()+604800, "/", ".fha.com", 0);
setcookie("CCID", getVariable('CCID'), time()+604800, "/", ".fha.com", 0);
setcookie("QTR", getVariable('QTR'), time()+604800, "/", ".fha.com", 0);
setcookie("CLK", getVariable('CLK'), time()+604800, "/", ".fha.com", 0);
setcookie("DCK", getVariable('DCK'), time()+604800, "/", ".fha.com", 0);
```

FYI - getVariable is function to $_REQUEST the CF variable in PHP.  I check my browser and I can't see these cookies, even when I try to revisit the page.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: I should mention the reason for going to php, is that I'm in the process of migrating the entire site from CF to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You set cookies in a browser.  In this case the "browser" is the `CFHTTP` tag which does not support cookies.  You can read the cookies that were set, they are returned in the cfhttp response, but they won't actually be written anywhere.

Comment: Also, the CFHTTP call happens on the server, not in your client browser.  They are two separate requests happening on separate machines.  You could probably do the POST via an Ajax or Javascript submission on the client side which would then set those cookies in the user's browser.

Comment: I've been using the cfhttp method POST to pass some form variables to a php redirect and it's worked just fine.  If cfhttp doesn't support cookies, what is the best way of paasing these values from CF to PHP?

Comment: Yes, you can POST all you like to PHP or any other server side language using CFHTTP. Thats not the question. You are expecting cookies to be written because of a CFHTTP call. The CFHTTP call happens on the server, not in the client browser. Say you had 1000 users on your site hitting that page, how would the server know which browser to write the cookies to?? That said, as I noted above, you could do the POST via Javascript. In that case, it would take place in the client browser and the cookies would be written. Otherwise, you are expecting client side behavior from a server side solution.

Comment: If I have the values stored inb an array on another PHP page on the site, can I just set the cookies from that?

Comment: Yes, from the CF side you could do a cflocation to the PHP page, then let PHP write the cookies. You just need to make sure you send the user to the PHP site, doing it all from the server is not enough.  You could also just write the cookies in CF, but I see you mentioned you are moving to PHP, so I guess this must be a piece by piece move.

Comment: It's not exactly true to say that CFHTTP doesn't support cookies. It does support sending cookies, and it does receive them. But it doesn't support passing them through to the response of the original request, which is what I think the OP is hoping for.

Comment: @JasonDean yeah, thats what I meant.  I noted that the response would have the cookies that were sent, but they don't actually function like he is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example above, you can think of your CFHTTP request as the "browser" that is making a request to the PHP page. The cookies you are setting in PHP are being returned to the CFHTTP result "cookieResponse". At that point they are still on the server, nothing has been returned to the initial client (the one that called the CF page to start with). If you want those to be set as cookies at this point to the end user's browser you need to then set them again using ColdFusion. <strike>Which means you'd have to parse the cookieResponse.header result, find the cookies,</strike> You can get the cookies out using cookieResponse.responseHeader["SET-COOKIE"] and set them to the end user's browser with cfheader

Like this

```
<cfset cookies = cookieResponse.responseHeader["set-cookie"] />
<cfloop from="1" to="#structCount(cookies)#" index="i">
    <cfheader name="SET-COOKIE" value="#cookies[i]#" />
</cfloop>
```