# Returning a PHP value to a Coldfusion page?

Tags: php, coldfusion, parameter-passing

I'm doing a cfhttp post to a PHP page:

```
<cfhttp method="Post" url="https://www.example.com/ssl/roundpoint.php" result="mlResponse"> 

<cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0"> 
<cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
<cfoutput>

    <cfif isdefined( "ppcid" )><cfhttpparam name="PPCID" type="formField" value="#PPCID#"></cfif>
    <cfif isdefined( "product")><cfhttpparam name="PRODUCT" type="formField" value="#PRODUCT#"></cfif>
    <cfif isdefined( "va_status" )><cfhttpparam name="VA_STATUS" type="formField" value="#VA_STATUS#"></cfif>
    <cfif isdefined( "qs_product")><cfhttpparam name="QS_PRODUCT" type="formField" value="#QS_PRODUCT#"></cfif>
    <cfif isdefined( "prop_st" ) and prop_st neq ""><cfhttpparam name="PROP_ST" type="formField" value="#PROP_ST#"></cfif>

</cfoutput>
</cfhttp>
```

On the PHP page, I do a cURL function, look for a specific value in the result and save it:

```
 $pstVars = '';

 if (count($_REQUEST) > 0) {
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value) {
       $pstVars .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
     }

    $pstVars .= 'ON_SUBMIT=YES';


    //the SSL/ORGANIC redirect API url 
    $url = 'https://www.example.com/ssl/redirect.php';


    //make the server-side redirect API call
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pstVars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //store the result from the API call
    $roundpoint_result = curl_exec($ch);

    // LOOKING FOR ROUNDPOINT FLAG
    $rpVals = substr($roundpoint_result, 0, 10);
```

For testing purposes, I've e-mailed myself the $rpVals value to make sure it's correct.  I need to pass that value back into the Coldfusion page.  I've tried passing the value into a cookie:

```
 setcookie('RPCOOKIE', $rpVals, time()+60*60*24*2, '/', '.example.com');
```

and tried to read it on the ColdFusion page:

```
<cfparam name="RPCOOKIE" default=""/>
<cfcookie name="RPCOOKIE" value="#RPCOOKIE#">
```

But I haven't had any luck with this, either setting the cookie or reading it in ColdFusion.  Any suggestions?

(FYI - The Coldfusion page will be re-written in PHP in a few weeks, but the client is requesting something time sensitive).

Comment: Wouldn't anything outputted on the php page be available in the return var? Is there any reason it's not just a web service with a response back?

Comment: As @dana suggested, anything output by php will be available in cfhttp.filecontent.

Comment: (Edit) Re: *Is there any reason it's not just a web service* Good question. If for some reason you must use cookies, remember `cfhttp` is not a browser. So you must [extract cookies from the cfhttp response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794117/coldfusion-form-values-to-php-setcookie). (As an aside, `cfcookie` is for *writing* cookies. To read cookies, use the [`COOKIE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html) scope. Though again, that does not apply here. Only to normal browser sessions).

Comment: Yeah I don't understand how if the `cfhttp.filecontent` returns the response - why can't you just alter the response content-type sent from the cURL function and have it pass you back an XML or JSON object containing what you need straight into the `.filecontent` obj and then parse that out in CF?